# Is it a good idea to overload begin/end for pointers to collections

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I really like the new concept of free `begin` `end` to write more generic algorithms and data structures. Currently it sometimes happens to me that I have to differentiate between calls `begin(range)` and `begin(*range)` when a type holds a reference to a collection as pointer. I thought about if it is a good idea to always provide an overload of begin/end for pointers for my own collection types.

```
struct Container {
    int values[3];
};

const int* begin(const Container& c);
const int* end(const Container& c);
const int* begin(const Container* c);
const int* end(const Container* c);

template<typename Range>
int Sum(const Range& range)
{
    return std::accumulate(begin(range), end(range), 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    Container c = {1, 2, 3};
    std::cout << Sum(c);
    std::cout << Sum(&c);
}
```

If this was a good idea why not provide a template for this:

```
template<typename Range>
auto begin(const Range* r) -> decltype(begin(*r)){
    using std::begin;
    return begin(*r);
}

template<typename Range>
auto end(const Range* r) -> decltype(end(*r)) { /* ... */ }

int main(void)
{
    Container c = {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3}
    std::cout << Sum(c);
    std::cout << Sum(&c);
    std::cout << Sum(v);
    std::cout << Sum(&v);
}
```

If this was a good idea why doesn't the standard library define it?

**My question is**: Is there anything wrong with a `template<typename R>
    auto begin(const R* r)` template? Are there any cases where this fails for some reason?

Comment: +1 for the question but I have to say that I struggle to see the benefit. I’d probably abstain from it.

Comment: If `Sum(&c)` works, then `Sum(&&c)` would also work (recursively); `Sum(&&&c)` too. Ad infinitum. So I don't think that is a good idea.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If i change type of an argument, field, variable etc. from reference to pointer, I don't have to change code to `begin(*x)`. In generic code I don't need specializations for pointers.

Comment: Why not `Sum(*c)`?  Generally, treating `U = T*` and `U = T&` and `U = T` identically should be done with caution -- a `U = T*` is not the same thing as a `U = T`.  As an example, `U tmp = u;`, or `U tmp; tmp = u;` or `swap(u, U())` all behave very differently when you have a pointer or reference instead of an instance.  Ie, in generic code you should have specializations for pointers.

Comment: @hansmaad does that happen often enough to be problematic? Also, do you have variables that are so ubiquitously used that changing that code is an unbearable chore?

Comment: As an aside, you can add in a sum specialization to read: `template<typename T> auto Sum( T const* t )->decltype(Sum(*t)) { return Sum(*t); }` and, as @Nawaz mentioned, `Sum(&&&&&c)` works -- you don't need specializations for pointers to pointers to pointers to pointers to pointers to pointers either.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes It's not a real problem to write `begin(*x)` but i prefer to write `begin(x)` if it cost 2 simple templates. @others I still try to understand the Sum(&&&&&c) thing.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do this you can no longer use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` overloaded for arrays:

```
Container c[2] = { };
std::accumulate(begin(c), end(c), 0);
```

This shouldn't compile, because you can't add `c[i]` to `0`, but it does because the `begin(Container*)` overloads are selected instead of the generic `std::begin(T (&)[N])` one.

For another example:

```
Container c[2] = { };
auto dist = std::distance(begin(c), end(c));
```

this should set `dist=2`, because the array has two elements, but instead you get `dist=3` because `end(*c) - begin(*c)` equals 3.

Comment: More generally, a problem occurs any time you have containers in containers.  It becomes ambiguous as to which level of coontainer begin/end should refer to.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, does it? I see an ambiguity for arrays of containers vs pointers to containers, due to the implicit array-to-pointer conversion, but I don't see how `vector<list<T>>` could match the proposed `begin(const Range*)` overload, or how `*r` would be a valid expression for arbitrary containers, it's only valid for arrays or pointers.